# dirvish doesn't backup NFS mount

Tags: rsync, nfs, incremental-backup

I do incremental backups using [dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/). (dirvish makes incremental backups using rsync and hardlinks).

This has worked perfectly on our old server (nothing fancy, just a linux box with one disk on `/`). On our new server we have a special mount for mass-storage (SQL dumps and other things). This is an NFS-mount.

**The trouble is that the content of the mount is not copied.**

I run the copy as root, so I should have all the rights.This is the content as it is on the live-server:

**live:/mnt**

```
drwxrwxrwx  5 ouruser      ouruser       4096 2011-03-31 10:14 nfs
```

**live:/mnt/nfs**

```
drwxr-xr-x  9 nobody        nogroup      4096 2011-04-05 13:36 sql-backup
```

**backup:/mnt**

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 anotheruser  anoutheruser  4096 2011-03-31 10:14 nfs
```

(and that is empty)

It's not clear at all to me why this is. Maybe it's got something to do with rights (the NFS uses a different rights system, right?), but AFAIK I should be able to read (and thus backup) the files. There is a lot of stuff on the internet about dirvish and copying TO NFS, but my target system is just a basic linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, and it is a bit trivial :)
From [the manual](http://wiki.edseek.com/howto:dirvish) (emph. mine)

> Depending on your backup strategy, you
>   may not want Dirvish to cross
>   filesystem boundaries when performing
>   backups. By default, the parameters
>   passed to rsync do not instruct it to
>   remain within a single mount point on
>   the target filesystem. If you want to
>   have a vault for each filesystem being
>   backed up, you will want to enabled
>   the boolean option xdev. If not
>   specified, **the default action is to
>   descend into all filesystems** that may
>   exist under the specified target.

Now for some reason one of the vaults had a config-file that overrides this default:

```
xdev: true
```

Removing that flag should fix my problems.